# Insert Date in TextBox - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I know that we can use function ***Date*** in forms for the insertion of the date. But for some dates (such as Hijri Shamsi and Hijri lunar history, etc.), this is impossible and difficult. So I wrote a code that works with the text box. But I think the code that I wrote can be simpler. Do you have a solution to make it simpler?
For example: checking the slash or preventing of Double message display for the moon and day error.

*Thanks in advance for the friends who respond.*

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    'To check the slash in the correct place
    If Mid(TextBox1, 1) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 2) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 3) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 4) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 6) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 7) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 9) = "/" Or Mid(TextBox1, 10) = "/" Then
        MsgBox "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
        SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")
    End If
    'Insert the slash automatically
    If TextBox1.TextLength = 8 Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Value, "0000/00/00")
    End If

    'Year Error!
    If Mid(TextBox1, 4) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Year Error!" & vbNewLine & "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
        With TextBox1
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Month Error!
    If TextBox1.TextLength = 10 Then
        If Mid(TextBox1.Value, 6, 2) = 0 Or Mid(TextBox1.Value, 6, 2) > 12 Then
            MsgBox "Month Error!" & vbNewLine & "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
            With TextBox1
                .SelStart = 5
                .SelLength = 2
                '.SelText = ""
            End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    'Day Error!
    If TextBox1.TextLength = 10 Then
        If Mid(TextBox1.Value, 9, 2) = 0 Or Mid(TextBox1.Value, 9, 2) > 31 Then
            MsgBox "Day Error!" & vbNewLine & "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
            With TextBox1
                .SelStart = 8
                .SelLength = 2
            End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub textbox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Accept only number and slash
    If Not Chr(KeyAscii) Like "[0-9,/ ]" Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        MsgBox "Only Numbers Allowed!" & vbNewLine & "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
        With TextBox1
            .SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the required format from the user is YYYYMMDD, do you really need to handle the `/`? The only reason I can think of is to support copying and pasting into the TextBox, but that's already completely unhandled.

Comment: Linked from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205970/36565). The code there technically "answers" this question, but is probably a bit out of scope for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar enough with the calendar forms you're dealing with, so please understand my example based on a western-style calendar.

The way you're performing some of your error checking somewhat obscures the values you'e checking. For example,

```
If Mid(TextBox1.Value, 6, 2) = 0 Or Mid(TextBox1.Value, 6, 2) > 12 Then
```

is a perfectly valid check, but you're overusing the `Mid` function. One suggestion is to parse the date string and pull out substrings into values you're looking for. As in:

```
Dim month As Long
month = CLng(Mid$(TextBox1.Value, 6, 2))
If (month = 0) Or (month > 12) Then
```

this makes more intuitive sense. Yes, it creates an extra variable, but it makes your code much more readable.

Here's my (untested) version of your code as another example of how it can be done. Notice that I'm separating the error checking into a separate function because it's more involved. (This way it isn't cluttering the main routine.)

> **EDIT:** Answer has been updated and tested. Changed the event code from `TextBox1_Change` and now catching two different events: `LostFocus` and `KeyDown` in order to kick off a validation when the user clicks away from the textbox or types <kbd>Enter</kbd> while in the textbox.

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum ValidationError
    LengthError
    FormatError
    YearError
    MonthError
    DayError
    NoErrors
End Enum

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                             ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = Asc(vbCr) Then
        ValidateDate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    ValidateDate
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateDate()
    With TextBox1
        Select Case InputIsValidated(.text)
            Case LengthError
                MsgBox "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD with only numbers and a '/'"
            Case FormatError
                MsgBox "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD with only numbers and a '/'"
            Case YearError
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = 4
                MsgBox "Invalid Year. Must be between 2015 and 2020"
            Case MonthError
                .SelStart = 5
                .SelLength = 2
                MsgBox "Invalid Month. Must be between 1 and 12"
            Case DayError
                .SelStart = 7
                .SelLength = 2
                MsgBox "Invalid Day. Must be between 1 and 31"
            Case NoErrors
                '--- nothing to do, it's good!
                MsgBox "It's good!"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Private Function InputIsValidated(ByRef text As String) As ValidationError
    '--- perform all sorts of checks to validate the input
    '    before any processing
    '--- MUST be the correct length
    If (Len(text) <> 8) And (Len(text) <> 10) Then
        InputIsValidated = LengthError
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- check if all characters are numbers
    Dim onlyNumbers As String
    onlyNumbers = Replace(text, "/", "")
    If Not IsNumeric(onlyNumbers) Then
        InputIsValidated = FormatError
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim yyyy As Long
    Dim mm As Long
    Dim dd As Long
    yyyy = Left$(onlyNumbers, 4)
    mm = Mid$(onlyNumbers, 5, 2)
    dd = Right$(onlyNumbers, 2)

    '--- only checks if the numbers are in range
    '    you can make this more involved if you want to check
    '    if, for example, the day for February is between 1-28
    If (yyyy < 2015) Or (yyyy > 2020) Then
        InputIsValidated = YearError
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (mm < 1) Or (mm > 12) Then
        InputIsValidated = MonthError
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (dd < 1) Or (dd > 31) Then
        InputIsValidated = DayError
        Exit Function
    End If

    text = onlyNumbers
    InputIsValidated = NoErrors
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @PeterT! Thanks. I tested your code. In section `TextBox1_Change()`, the error message (`EndWith`)! Meanwhile, there are `End If` added at the part.

Comment: Hi @PeterT!  I replace `End If` with `End Select`. But by entering the first number, Error gives. Because you process check before end insert date.

Comment: Hi @PeterT! I failed to execute your written code. Errors are different!

Comment: I've updated and tested the code. Please note the edit description. I posted this yesterday while I was away from a workstation, sorry for the confusion. As a further note, if you continue to use the `TextBox1_Change` event, you'll catch every single keystroke, and then attempt to validate the entry. I think waiting until the user indicates they're finished makes for a cleaner experience.

Comment: Hi @PeterT! I Thanks. Please edit Case `DayError .SelStart = 7` to `DayError .SelStart = 8`.

Comment: Hi @PeterT! The code written by you, although it is clean and good, but many of my code items are not included in it: 1- Correct the date format if only the number is entered. 2- Check typing the date in the slash format, in the Moment. 3- Selecting the wrong date, in slash and no slash mode (slash scanning is required for cases where the date is copied and pasted or some users are accustomed to entering slashes). However, Thank you for teaching you to write a clean code.

Comment: For the most part, answers on SO are targeted solutions to solve the errors you might be getting in your code, or to help understand how to set up a solution. Hopefully with my example above, it can give you a working set of code from which to add in the specific code items you need.

Comment: Hi @PeterT! I corrected the code with your help. To display, I put it in the answer section. Thanks if you take a look and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PeterT, I corrected the code with guidance @PeterT and I give it to all the interested people. *Enjoy it*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum ValidationError
    LengthError
    FormatError
    YearError
    MonthError
    DayError
    NoErrors
End Enum

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    'To check the slash in the correct place
    If TextBox1.TextLength = 10 Then
        If InStr(Left(TextBox1, 4), "/") Or InStr(Mid(TextBox1, 6, 2), "/") Or InStr(Mid(TextBox1, 9, 2), "/") <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
            With TextBox1
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.text)
            End With
        End If
    End If
    'Insert the slash automatically
    If TextBox1.TextLength = 8 Then
        If InStr(TextBox1, "/") Then
        'nothing
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Value, "0000/00/00")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub textbox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Accept only number and slash
    If Not Chr(KeyAscii) Like "[0-9,/ ]" Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        MsgBox "Only Numbers Allowed!" & vbNewLine & "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = Asc(vbCr) Then
        ValidateDate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    ValidateDate
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateDate()
    With TextBox1
        Select Case InputIsValidated(.text)
            Case LengthError
                MsgBox "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD with only numbers and a '/'"
            Case FormatError
                MsgBox "Please insert date with format: YYYYMMDD or YYYY/MM/DD with only numbers and a '/'"
            Case YearError
                .SelStart = 0
                .SelLength = 4
                MsgBox "Invalid Year. Must be between 2015 and 2020"
            Case MonthError
                .SelStart = 5
                .SelLength = 2
                MsgBox "Invalid Month. Must be between 1 and 12"
            Case DayError
                .SelStart = 8
                .SelLength = 2
                MsgBox "Invalid Day. Must be between 1 and 31"
            Case NoErrors
                '--- nothing to do, it's good!
                MsgBox "It's good!"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Private Function InputIsValidated(ByRef text As String) As ValidationError
    '--- perform all sorts of checks to validate the input
    '    before any processing
    '--- MUST be the correct length
    If InStr(TextBox1, "/") And TextBox1.TextLength < 10 Then
        InputIsValidated = FormatError
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim yyyy As Long
    Dim mm As Long
    Dim dd As Long
    yyyy = Left$(TextBox1, 4)
    mm = Mid$(TextBox1, 6, 2)
    dd = Right$(TextBox1, 2)

    '--- only checks if the numbers are in range
    '    you can make this more involved if you want to check
    '    if, for example, the day for February is between 1-28
    If (yyyy < 2015) Or (yyyy > 2020) Then
        InputIsValidated = YearError
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (mm < 1) Or (mm > 12) Then
        InputIsValidated = MonthError
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (dd < 1) Or (dd > 31) Then
        InputIsValidated = DayError
        Exit Function
    End If

    text = TextBox1
    InputIsValidated = NoErrors
End Function
```